Where is the "user created" event on Firebase Functions V2?
There is only functions to handle before user creation.
Is the migration to V2 incomplete? Where is the onUserCreated?


I am currently migrating as well and I am stuck at online testing. Have you got there yet, maybe we can help one another.

In regard for the triggers I had to keep the V1, the issue is Google is pushing us to migrate yet, there are plenty of things that are not yet 100%.

When I receive an email form Google telling me the following: Additionally, the firebase-functions Node.js SDK will begin defaulting to the v2 API instead of the v1 API. The v2 API is available now at firebase-functions/v2.
I would assume that the events and triggers would be supported as well… or at least mentioned to be not.

As you will read in the documentation on "Extend Firebase Authentication with Cloud Functions":

Cloud Functions for Firebase (2nd gen) does not provide support for
the events and triggers described in this guide

In other words, Cloud Functions triggered in response to the creation and deletion of Firebase user accounts are only available in V1 for the moment (i.e. at the date of writing) .
